# 301 redirect https:// to https://www. not woking (READ QUESTION)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

Please read this unique question. Don't refer me to other posts I can't find the answer as this is unique

All http:// and http:// works redirecting to https://www.example.com/

My issue -> https://example.com/ won't redirect all file urls .png .jpeg .xml for example to the desired https://www.example.com/

Please see .htaccess code below

```
# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>

#Begin Really Simple Security
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
#End Really Simple Security
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: “Please read this unique question. Don't refer me to other posts I can't find the answer as this is unique” - this is not a good way to start a question here. I have no doubt you tried many things, so instead I’d encourage you to flip this around and tell us the things you did try, possibly linking to sources, along with the result. Please don’t take this comment negatively, either, I’m just trying to help you get a question that is more likely to be answered.

Comment: Your example uses both domain.com and example.com. I’m certain you are using both to represent the real domain, but just for clarity can you update this with just one, ideally the latter? It sounds pedantic, I know, but htaccess is finicky and we want to make sure the simple things are correct.

Comment: Lastly, why do these URLs exist in the first place? Are they in the database that way? Would a simple search and replace be better, since actively linking to redirects is discouraged for SEO? If these URLs exist for other reasons, that’s fine, I’m just asking for clarity.

Comment: Even without changing the links by means of a search and replace: such files _usually_ are referenced using _relative_ links from within a page. Which means you won't have to redirect, since the page _is_ already redirected according to what you write. So do we have to assume that those files you mention are requested independent of a web page referencing them?

Comment: This one contains an issue anyway: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`. I doubt you _really_ want to redirect to `wwwexample.com` which is what it would do.

Comment: Why would you expect requests to `https://example.com/whatever` getting redirected to `https://www.example.com/whatever` ? You have no traces of any such rule in your setup. You'd have to add that.

Comment: It could be that your wordpress logic is responsible for such a redirection, we cannot say. That might explain the behavior you observe, since the wordpress rules _explicitly_ make an exception for existing files.

Comment: These redirects should be placed higher up, they should come _before_ the internal rewrites WP performs.

Comment: @arkascha how would I achieve this? I've tried a few things and it either crashes the site or spins it into a constant 301 redirect loop...

I just need the files/images that are https:// to be forced to go to https:// www without creating 404 errors

Comment: I just need the files/images that are https:// to be forced to go to https:// www without creating 404 errors... the rest of the redirects work fine
@ChrisHaas

Comment: How would you achieve _what_ ?

Comment: @arkascha its ok I've got it working, <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WP_Encryption_Force_SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WP_Encryption_Force_SSL

#Begin Really Simple Security
Options -Indexes
#End Really Simple Security
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```